# Amazon Kindle Paperwhite 2 - Reading progress line has disappeared

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, time-to-read

Recently I've updated my Amazon Kindle Paperwhite (2nd gen) to the 5.7.3 version.
And everything was fine.

But then suddenly while reading a book I'd noticed that a line with my current book reading progress and estimated time had disappeared from the bottom of the screen. I know that previously there was a setting "Read Progress" in a book menu, but now I can not find it either.

So now I can see my current position in a book only when I tap the screen and look for this info in the footer block.

Does anyone know, how to get back that useful line on the screen? Maybe the setting was moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried tapping on the bottom left corner of the screen while reading a book? You can switch among various options:

- %, Loc
- %, time left in chapter
- %, time left in book
- blank (ie, your current state)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! The reason is that the space for tapping is incredibly small - I've just turned pages all the time while tapping. But, if you manage to point exactly at the corner, then it works.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! I was shocked that Amazon did not clearly make this setting available. It’s basically a hidden Easter egg.

Comment: Note if you have continuous scroll on you have to turn it off first.  Setting will persist when you turn continuous scroll back on.

Comment: Thank you. Has been bugging me too. Appreciate the fix!

Comment: Not being able to track my reading progress has been driving me nuts..Been doing LOTS of reading the last couple of months..I never would have thought of tapping the bottom corner..it works ..thank you

Answer (score 2):

Reading progress is now located when you press the Aa icon.